Why is there a ‘silent e’ in the word ‘minute’ (as in minutes and seconds)?
In researching the silent e, is the silent e added to the end of the word minute (as in minutes and seconds) to indicate the schwa sound of the u? Or was the silent e pronounced at some point?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

No, it doesn’t "indicate" that the letter u is pronounced as a schwa in the word, although it indeed is so: /ˈmɪnət/ is the noun as opposed to /mɑjˈn(j)ut/ the adjective.
It’s there because of its history. The word was minute in French when we grabbed it for Middle English, with the final e still pronounced as a schwa then. It no longer is so, but we still use the Middle English spelling system despite no longer pronouncing things that way.
The OED gives evidence that it was pronounced with its stress on the second syllable when it was first borrowed into English, when it had the French /yː/ sound even as late as 1619. That’s more like the adjective is still pronounced. The wealth of historical spellings during the Middle English to Early Modern English transition show that the stress was shifting, which caused the reduction of the second syllable once no longer stressed. Nonetheless, we settled on the minute spelling for both the noun and the adjective.

"The Middle English spelling" of this word (and pretty much any word) isn't a thing. The OED says possible M.E. spellings were: mynet, mynnate, mynvte, mynwt, minut, mynut, mynute, minute, mynewte, mynite, mynitt, myniute, minuit, mynuit. The reason that it's spelled minute today is undoubtedly because somebody sometime during the 18th century decided that it should be spelled the way it is in French, probably for etymological reasons.

@PeterShor  Your right, sorry. Spellings were many and varied in Middle English. I was trying to summarize the part where they write: "the multiplicity of forms in the second syllable suggests that a shift of primary stress to the first syllable must have occurred early in at least some varieties of English".
